# Alguém consegue me explicar como esse código funciona?

Tags: javascript, regex, funções

Não consigo entender o uso do `prototype.allReplace` e nem o uso do `RegExp`.
O que são esses parâmetros?

```
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
    }
    return retStr;
};

console.log('T35t3 d3 35t4g1o'.allReplace({4: 'a', 3: 'e', 1: 'i', 5: 's'}));
```

Não tem uma forma mais simples de fazer essa troca de números por letras?

Answer (score 5):

Colocas duas perguntas:

- como funciona o código
- se não há forma mais simples

A segunda pergunta gera respostas baseadas em opiniões, depende do caso, da aplicação e dos dados disponíveis... por isso não vou responder.
Em relação à primeira pergunta o código funciona assim:

Quando defines uma função no protótipo de um objeto nativo como "String", o `this` dentro dessa função será a *String*.

Quando tens um objeto tens pares de chaves e valores. Por exemplo `{foo: 123}` tem a chave "foo" e o valor "123". Assim quando usas `var x in obj` vais percorrer todas as chaves de um dado objeto, cujo valor fica guardado dentro da variável `x`.

Assim, dentro desse ciclo/loop, com o `replace` o código troca todas as ocorrências da chave pelo "valor" dessa chave. O segundo argumento "g" da RegExp quer dizer exatamente "todas as ocorrências".

No final, depois do loop retorna a frase com as trocas feitas.

Dá uma olhada a este exemplo para ver em detalhe  que se passa dentro do loop:

```js
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
  let retStr = this.toString();
  for (const x in obj) {
    console.log(
      retStr,
      new RegExp(x, 'g'),
      obj[x],
      retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x])
    );

    retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
  }
  return retStr;
};

console.log('T35t3 d3 35t4g1o'.allReplace({
  4: 'a',
  3: 'e',
  1: 'i',
  5: 's'
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436959/112052) já explica como o código funciona, então vou focar na sua outra pergunta:

> *Não tem uma forma mais simples de fazer essa troca de números por letras?*

Tem outras maneiras de fazer, mas se elas são mais simples ou não, é uma questão de opinião. De qualquer forma, vamos à elas.

---

### Opção 1: criar uma única regex em vez de várias

Uma característica do seu código é que ele cria várias expressões regulares, uma para cada chave do objeto passado (no caso, uma regex para cada dígito). Talvez alguém ache que é "mais simples" criar uma única regex (pode ser um pouco "melhor" por criar menos coisas e fazer tudo de uma vez, por exemplo, mas novamente, é questão de opinião).

Podemos juntar todas as chaves da regex em uma única expressão e fazer um único `replace`:

```js
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    let r = new RegExp(Object.keys(obj).join('|'), 'g');
    return this.replace(r, function(match) {
        return obj[match];
    });
};

console.log('T35t3 d3 35t4g1o'.allReplace({4: 'a', 3: 'e', 1: 'i', 5: 's'}));
```

No caso, eu pego todas as chaves de `obj` (que no caso são os dígitos 4, 3, 1 e 5) e junto tudo em uma única expressão: `4|3|1|5`. Essa regex usa [alternância](https://regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), o que quer dizer que ela pega qualquer um destes dígitos.

Em seguida, eu uso uma [função no segundo parâmetro do `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters), que por sua vez recebe como parâmetro o *match* (ou seja, o trecho que foi encontrado pela regex). Eu sei que este trecho pode ser qualquer um dos dígitos (4, 3, 1 ou 5), então eu retorno o valor correspondente (as letras `a`, `e`, `i` ou `s`, obtidas do próprio `obj`), que será o valor usado na substituição.

No final, todos os dígitos são substituídos pelas respectivas letras.

Obs: se todas as opções só possuem um caractere (no caso, todas são apenas um dígito), a regex também poderia ser `[4315]`. Mas eu usei alternância para deixar o código mais "genérico", assim ele pode receber strings de vários tamanhos. Por exemplo, se eu quiser trocar `abc` por `xyz`:

```js
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    let r = new RegExp(Object.keys(obj).join('|'), 'g');
    return this.replace(r, function(match) {
        return obj[match];
    });
};

console.log('abc 123 abc'.allReplace({'abc': 'xyz'}));
```

---

### Opção 2: não usar regex

Talvez seja mais simples percorrer a string e ir substituindo seus caracteres um a um, usando o `obj` para substituir os caracteres desejados, e mantendo os demais:

```js
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    let s = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let c = this.charAt(i);
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            s += obj[c];
        } else {
            s += c;
        }
    }
    return s;
};

console.log('T35t3 d3 35t4g1o'.allReplace({4: 'a', 3: 'e', 1: 'i', 5: 's'}));
```

Para cada caractere da string, eu uso [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) para verificar se `obj` contém uma chave com aquele caractere. Caso tenha, eu uso o respectivo valor na substituição, e caso não tenha, eu mantenho o mesmo caractere da string original.

A diferença para a primeira opção é que, como estou percorrendo os caracteres um a um, não é mais possível trocar trechos maiores (como o exemplo anterior que troca `abc` por `xyz`).

---

Enfim, estas são algumas alternativas ao seu código. Se é mais simples ou não, vai da opinião de cada um...